# Good Jewish Blogs about the Modern Hebrew language?

Tags: hebrew, product-recommendation, internet

Are there any good Jewish Blogs about the Modern Hebrew language?

Comment: about the Hebrew language

Comment: Hello Matthew miller and welcome to mi.yodeya! Thank you for your broad but interesting question. As others have said before me, it certainly depends on what information on the Hebrew language you are looking for. There are so many blogs catering to so many different niches. In fact, even the term "Hebrew language" is a bit ambiguous as it has gone through many forms in different eras of history and locations. Consider specifying what type of blog you seek or for what purpose.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.balashon.com/

Comment: haha. nope it is not.

Comment: I remember balashon in its heyday...

Answer (score 5):

Best is a matter of taste, but here are a few that you might enjoy:

http://blog.tapuz.co.il/einat3 - modern hebrew

http://www.thmrsite.com/?page_id=6 - Hebrew (and Farsi, linguistics, etc.)

http://hebrewlog.blogspot.com/ - modern hebrew

http://yitzhakavinery.wordpress.com/ - About Yitzchak Avinery who was a Hebrew language scholar and inventor of Hebrew words, an Avshalom Kor of his day

http://haharoni.wordpress.com/ - modern Hebrew (also other subjects)

http://www.dorbanot.com/ - modern Hebrew, slang

http://hasagot.wordpress.com/ - blog about mistakes, interesting findings in the classic Even Shoshan Hebrew dictionary (very niche audience!)

http://benyehuda.org/blog/ - blog discussing classic Hebrew literature

Other Resources:

http://www.icast.co.il/default.aspx?p=Podcast&id=363234 - podcast for Avraham Kor, a guru of the Hebrew language popular in Israel

http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=3270207030CC172E - YouTube videos of short clips explaining interesting aspects of the Hebrew language by Avraham Kor

** http://www.safa-ivrit.org/ **- not written in a blog format, rather an article format, but still very interesting insights into the Hebrew language, very popular among Hebrew enthusiasts

http://hebrew-academy.huji.ac.il/Pages/default.aspx - homepage for the National Academy for Hebrew Language

Unfortunately, balashon is the only serious blog about Hebrew written in English that I could find.

Comment: "**Avshalom** Kor", not Abraham! :) <br>
I'm uploader of Kor's Hebrew corner to YT, and I'm the operator of Avinery's blog. Regards,<br>
Or

Answer (score 0):

Not a blog as such, but a resource centre for those learning modern Hebrew:
http://www.hebrew.ecott.ch